# Has anyone succeeded to run mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

I still can not get mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main (mip_sdk_ubuntu1804_file_1.8.97) running  Ubuntu 18.04 .

I do get the following error after compilation with msbuild

````
*#/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug# mono ```./MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.exe

Unhandled Exception:
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: LoadLibrary assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.UnsafeNativeMethods.LoadLibraryWindows(string)
  at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.UnsafeNativeMethods.LoadLibrary (System.String dllToLoad) [0x00007] in <5d913da122e246aeb9d44ad373706d2f>:0
  at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.Loader.LoadDlls (System.String dllFolder, System.String dllName, System.String[] dllDependencies) [0x00021] in <5d913da122e246aeb9d44ad373706d2f>:0
  at Microsoft.InformationProtection.MIP.Initialize (Microsoft.InformationProtection.MipComponent mipComponent, System.String path) [0x00030] in <5d913da122e246aeb9d44ad373706d2f>:0
  at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Action..ctor (Microsoft.InformationProtection.ApplicationInfo appInfo) [0x00020] in <ef313698562f4c0e81c7eb42440dde68>:0
  at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0002b] in <ef313698562f4c0e81c7eb42440dde68>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: LoadLibrary assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.UnsafeNativeMethods.LoadLibraryWindows(string)
  at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.UnsafeNativeMethods.LoadLibrary (System.String dllToLoad) [0x00007] in <5d913da122e246aeb9d44ad373706d2f>:0
  at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.Loader.LoadDlls (System.String dllFolder, System.String dllName, System.String[] dllDependencies) [0x00021] in <5d913da122e246aeb9d44ad373706d2f>:0
  at Microsoft.InformationProtection.MIP.Initialize (Microsoft.InformationProtection.MipComponent mipComponent, System.String path) [0x00030] in <5d913da122e246aeb9d44ad373706d2f>:0
  at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Action..ctor (Microsoft.InformationProtection.ApplicationInfo appInfo) [0x00020] in <ef313698562f4c0e81c7eb42440dde68>:0
  at MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0002b] in <ef313698562f4c0e81c7eb42440dde68>:0*
````

What do i do wrong?

Thanks

P.S. Compilation logs:

*root@:~/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main# msbuild /restore

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0 for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
Build started 3/28/2021 7:27:45 PM.
Project "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.sln" on node 1 (Restore target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
_GetAllRestoreProjectPathItems:
  Determining projects to restore...
Restore:
  Restoring packages for /root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.csproj...
  Committing restore...
  Generating MSBuild file /root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/obj/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file /root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/obj/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Writing assets file to disk. Path: /root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/obj/project.assets.json
  Restored /root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.csproj (in 1.14 sec).
  NuGet Config files used:
      /root/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config
  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Done Building Project "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.sln" (Restore target(s)).
Project "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.sln" (1:2) is building "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.csproj" (2:6) on node 1 (default targets).
/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2101,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. [/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.csproj]
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  /usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Roslyn/csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:/root/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.windowsruntime/4.6.0/ref/netstandard2.0/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.7.2-api/Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.identity.client/4.24.0/lib/net461/Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll /reference:/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.informationprotection.file.ubuntu1804/1.8.97/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.InformationProtection.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.7.2-api/mscorlib.dll "/root/.nuget/packages/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates/4.3.2/runtimes/win/lib/net461/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll" to "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll".
  Creating "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/obj/Debug//MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.csproj.CopyComplete" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.informationprotection.file.ubuntu1804/1.8.97/dotnet/linux2/native/release/libmip_dotnet.so" to "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug/libmip_dotnet.so".
  Copying file from "/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.informationprotection.file.ubuntu1804/1.8.97/build/native/bins/release/x86_64/libmip_protection_sdk.so" to "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug/libmip_protection_sdk.so".
  Copying file from "/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.informationprotection.file.ubuntu1804/1.8.97/build/native/bins/release/x86_64/libmip_file_sdk.so" to "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug/libmip_file_sdk.so".
  Copying file from "/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.informationprotection.file.ubuntu1804/1.8.97/build/native/bins/release/x86_64/libmip_upe_sdk.so" to "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug/libmip_upe_sdk.so".
  Creating directory "bin/Debug/x64".
  Copying file from "/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.informationprotection.file.ubuntu1804/1.8.97/build/native/bins/release/x86_64/libmip_core.so" to "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug/libmip_core.so".
  Copying file from "/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.informationprotection.file/1.8.97/dotnet/win7-x64/native/release/mip_dotnet.dll" to "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug/x64/mip_dotnet.dll".
  Copying file from "/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.informationprotection.file/1.8.97/build/native/bins/release/amd64/libbz2-1.dll" to "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug/x64/libbz2-1.dll".
  Copying file from "/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.informationprotection.file/1.8.97/build/native/bins/release/amd64/libffi-7.dll" to "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug/x64/libffi-7.dll".
  Copying file from "/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.informationprotection.file/1.8.97/build/native/bins/release/amd64/libgio-2.0-0.dll" to "/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/bin/Debug/x64/libgio-2.0-0.dll".
"/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.sln" (default target) (1:2) ->
"/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.csproj" (default target) (2:6) ->
(ResolveAssemblyReferences target) ->
  /usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2101,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. [/root/azure/mipsdk-dotnet-file-quickstart-main/mip-sdk-dotnet-quickstart/MipSdkDotNetQuickstart.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:03.42*
```

Answer (score 0):

That project is a .NET Framework project and won’t run on Ubuntu.

This is a work in progress that I haven’t yet moved to Azure Samples, so it’s incomplete. It will build on Ubuntu though, as it’s .NET Core. Make sure to install the dependencies from the readme and update the app settings to your own client and tenant ID.

https://github.com/tommoser/mipsdk-dotnetcore-filesdk-sample/

I’ll hopefully have this moved to azure-samples when we release 1.9 in the next few weeks. I’ll also work to update that other project to .NET 5.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, what is the best/safe/reliable way to run the AIP tools on Ubuntu (or any other Linux OS family) in order to add protection to PDF files?

Comment: .NET Core or native C++ are both supported on Ubuntu 18.04, Debian 9, and CentOS 7. We don't have any native AIP tools (Client, scanner, PowerShell) on Linux.